# Problem using a binding on a dependency property WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to use the IsHighlighted dependency property on the CustomView class. It works as expected when I pass it a hard bool value, but it doesnt work when I pass it a binding. Anyone know why?

Also should I be calling OnPropertyChanged in the IsHighlighted setter?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel>

    <!-- The data context is set properly -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="50"/>
    
    <!-- This works! -->
    <views:CustomView IsHighlighted="true"/>

    <!-- This does not! -->
    <views:CustomView IsHighlighted="{Binding Path=One}"/>

</StackPanel>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; }
    }

    private bool _one;

    public bool One
    {
        get { return _one; }
        set { _one = value; }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Text = "bound text!";
        One = true;
    }
}
```

CustomView.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid Background="{Binding Path=CurrentBackground, 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                               AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomView}, AncestorLevel=1}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsHighlighted}" FontSize="40"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CustomView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CustomView : UserControl
{
    public CustomView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHighlightedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
          name: "IsHighlighted",
          propertyType: typeof(bool),
          ownerType: typeof(CustomView)
        );

    public bool IsHighlighted
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsHighlightedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsHighlightedProperty, value);
    }

    public Brush CurrentBackground
    {
        get 
        {
            if (IsHighlighted)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); // highlighted
            else
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White); // not highlighted
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `IsHighlighted="{Binding Path=One}"` does not work because the current DataContext object  - i.e. the source object of the Binding - does not expose the One property (or should it be called `On`?). This is because you have explicitly set the DataContext to hold a reference to the control, not the view model of the MainWindow. A control with bindable properties should never explicitly set its own DataContex because that breaks any standard, DataContext-based Bindings of the control's properties.

Comment: You should have noticed a data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you had run your application in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

First remove line `DataContext = this;`. User control will inherit `DataContext` from his parent (in this case `MainWindow.xaml` and context will be `MainViewModel`).

Another question is that you properly set DataContext to your `MainWindow`. Did you set `DataContext` of your `MainWindow.xaml` like

```
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

If not, do it somewhere in `MainWindow.cs` (for example in constructor). The `DataContext` property is the default source of your bindings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Second thing is, you need to call `PropertyChanged` in your `MainWindowViewModel` `One` property setter.

```
public bool One
{
    get { return _one; }
    set 
    { 
       _one = value; 
       OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I am expecting that your `ViewModelBase` is implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. If not you will need to implement it. In your case, it will work without the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation because you set the `One` property in constructor. But when you want to change this property in some logic in your ViewModel, you will need to notify the view that the `One` property is changing/changed (you will do it with INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-6.0

One remark to these lines of code in Xaml.

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Path=CurrentBackground, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                           AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomView}, AncestorLevel=1}}">
```

A better way how to change the background is to create a ValueConverter like.

```
  public class BackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
  {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         return (bool)value ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) : SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
  }
```

Usage:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding IsHighlighted,
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CustomView},
                   Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
```

Comment: Even better than a Converter would be a DataTrigger. In either case, note that the Binding of the Background property to IsHighlighted would also need `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CustomView}`.

Comment: Why the Binding would also need  `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:CustomView}`  ? It is a property of MainViewModel, so you can bind it directly like `Background="{Binding IsHighlighted, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}"` . O i am missing something ?

Comment: It's a property of the control.

Comment: Control properrty is `CurrentBackground` not `IsHighlighted`.

Comment: Read the question. IsHighlighted is declared right before CurrentBackground.

Comment: Oh yes. My bad in answer .. that should be `Background="{Binding One, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}"`

Comment: That would a bad advice. A control should not know a specific view model. It should expose bindable properties like IsHighlighted.

Comment: That's true. I will delete this advice. Thanks for correction.

Comment: I already did that on your behalf. Consider showing a DataTrigger in a Grid Style for how to implement this without a Converter.